# Covered queries and find all (no filter)

Tags: mongodb, optimization, indexing

I am not sure if it is possible, I'm just curious.
I have a region collection with the purpose of being loaded to a web dropdown. Not the big thing there.

```
{
    _id:"some numeric id",
    name:"region name",
}
```

and having the index created like `db.regions.createIndex({name:1})`

I tried both `db.regions.find({},{_id:0}).sort(name:1)` and without the sort.
Using the `explain` shows that the `totalDocsExamined` is greater than zero, so that means that it is not a covered query if I understood the concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a covered query, you have to explicitly list each of the covered fields in the projection:

```js
db.regions.find({}, {_id:0, name: 1}).sort({name:1})
```

If you only exclude `_id`, you're telling MongoDB to include *all* fields besides `_id`. You know that all your docs only have a `name` field, but MongoDB doesn't so you have to be explicit.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! I misunderstood the concept a bit, I thought it was enough supressing the non-indexed fields.

Comment: Not listed in the answer, but in order to get a covered query you must also sort the query based on the indexed field. If you did not include the sort term, you would not received a covered query.